# Load data into PostgreSQL fails with foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, ora2pg

I am loading data into Postgresql using ora2pg tool by following command

```
C:\ora2pg-23.1>ora2pg -t COPY -o data.sql -b F:\otopg\NCP\PG_Data -c C:\ora2pg\ora2pg.conf
[========================>] 256/256 tables (100.0%) end of scanning.

SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
SET synchronous_commit TO off;
```

DBD::Pg::db pg_putcopyend failed: ERROR:  insert or update on table "attribute" violates foreign key constraint "fk2_attibute"
DETAIL:  Key (attribute_category_id)=(2) is not present in table "attribute_category". at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Ora2Pg.pm line 14716.
FATAL: ERROR:  insert or update on table "attribute" violates foreign key constraint "fk2_attibute"
DETAIL:  Key (attribute_category_id)=(2) is not present in table "attribute_category".
Aborting export...

I am trying to run some queries to disable trigger but it's not working

```
ALTER TABLE attribute_category DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE attribute DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE category DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_19295" is a system trigger

Total execution time: 00:00:00.218

`SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` This works but same error in loading

Also `set session_replication_role to replica`; does not work because admin login can not be superuser

Can some expert help here. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are doing a bulk load, maybe dropping all FK constraints first, then do the bulk load, then re-create the FKs again is easier to manage (and probably faster as well).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the quick response. I got script like this[ alter table npp.claim_type drop constraint fk1_claim_type FOREIGN KEY (claim_group_id) REFERENCES npp.claim_group(claim_group_id) deferrable initially immediate;]. The first part is working but it shows Started executing query at Line 1
Commands completed successfully
11:58:19 PMStarted executing query at Line 1
syntax error at or near "FOREIGN"
Total execution time: 00:00:00.389. Any suggestion please

Comment: I got it. For adding we need FOREIGN KEY but for dropping just need constraint name. Thank you so much.